# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with xml (google places api)

Tags: json, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to work with the google places api for a little project.
I want to display all shops that are near me. I tried the following AJAX request with the no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error as a result. After some research I understand why I get this error, but I can't find a solid solution (I dont wanna install a plugin because it has to work on all computers).

A lot of people say to use dataType jsonp, which I have used before, but when I use this (and change the type to json) I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" because the response I get uses : instead of = (I think).

I have been searching a lot of information and tried a lot of things, hopefully you guys can help me out.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?',
    data: {
        key: "MY KEY",
        query: "supermarket",
        location: "x,y",
        radius: "5000",
        opennow: "true"
    }
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data)
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("fail: " + textStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CORS headers are not set for Places API web service on Google backend servers. So you won't be able to call Places API web service from the client side JavaScript code due to the Same-Origin policy of the browsers.

In order to use Places on client side JavaScript you have to use a Places library of Google Maps JavaScript API. The places library has nearby and text search functionality very similar to the corresponding web service.

For further details please have a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Hope it helps!